# I can't use a Dynamic concatenation in Azure Function Name inside Data Factory pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a concat expression defined in the Function Name setting of an Azure Function in my pipeline, where it concatenates the API Query with the current filename that I want to run on this function. When I debug the pipeline, it fails without giving me any feedback. It just says "AzureFunction failed:"

If I manually insert the string, it works fine.

the concat expression is:

```
@concat('HttpTrigger?filename=', variables('filename'))
```

I'm new to Azure, any way I can debug this?

Answer (score 2):

**try this way:**
@concat(variables('FirstName') ,variables('LastName'))

Answer (score 0):

You could use Set [Variable Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity) with your Azure Function Activity.

[image]
In the Variable Activity, set the value of the variable.

[image]

Then refer the variable in the Azure Function Activity:

```
@concat('HttpTriggerJS1?name=',variables('name'))
```

Comment: I tried that, same thing happened. When I set a variable and use it on the Function Name setting, if I check the input later, it shows the command, and not the concatenated value, should it be this way?